# Cambiar la etiqueta de [tsql] por [transact-sql]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

No tiene mucho, tuve que hacer una pregunta relacionada con `transact-sql` y vi que la etiqueta se llamaba `tsql`.

[tsql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) me parece una etiqueta demasiado corta y menos clara que [transact-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transact-sql).

Creo que [tsql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) puede causar confusiones, por lo que propongo cambiar el tag para llamarlo como he sugerido.

Además ayer queriendo sugerir una edición de etiqueta, sin darme cuenta hice una nueva etiqueta llamada transact-sql, por lo que también estaría guay borrarla y dejar solo una.

Comment: ¿Por qué no tenerlas como sinónimas? Así quien vaya a preguntar podrá usar cualquiera de las dos y todo apuntará al mismo lugar.

Comment: ¿Tener etiquetas sinonimas es igual a tener dos etiquetas iguals con el mismo significado pero distinto nombre? si es así... ¿No estaríamos dividiendo preguntas sobre el mismo tema por ello?

Comment: Sinónimas quiere decir que las dos apuntan al mismo lugar y una de ellas es la principal. Por tanto, todas las sinónimas acaban siendo la misma a efectos prácticos. Mira por ejemplo aquí en Meta [meta-tag:discusión] y [meta-tag:discussion]. Suele usarse en precisamente estos casos, para evitar la dispersión de un tema en múltiples etiquetas equivalentes.

Comment: No conocía esa función, me parece perfecto. Ayer puse transact y no encontraba tsql, me costó un par de minutos jsjs

Comment: De hecho, en [so] son sinónimos, siendo [tag:tsql] la principal. Si nadie se opone, yo estoy de acuerdo en hacerlas sinónimos.

Comment: Mira, tienes más info en [Privilegios > Crear sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). El sistema de sinónimos es un poco farragoso y cuesta mucho conseguir que se acepte uno, por lo que aprovechemos que @Pikoh nos lee para que un moderador lo haga :P

Comment: Voto por crearlas como sinónomos.

Comment: Esto no pasó, siguen ambas vivas. Y no tengo tantos puntos pa poder hacer la sugerencia :/  Heeeelp!